# .htaccess file is not recognized by PHP website

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

```
 http://mywebsite.com/
```

to

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

I want to highlight that these are 2 different pages, in non www version,we have thank you message only, but www version is the actual page we wanted to show it to customer.

Problem is that when I am trying to use `.htaccess` file through FTP, it is not recognizing the `.htaccess` file.

This website is made up on `PHP`. I tried meta tags redirection too, which result in blank page as it have default tags in all page.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: it has to be called `.htaccess`, `.htacces` will be ignored.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the content of your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gerald, but it is .htaccess only, It was typing error in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` is not a feature of PHP. it is a feature of Apache http server. so, options are:

1. the host doesn't use Apache (and uses nginx — headers actually confirm this version)
2. even if it Apache, htaccess parsing is disabled.

In both cases, you should contact server administrators for support

Comment: Thanks Jimi for the reply, Let me check with my server administrator.

Answer (score 1):

If .htaccess is not an option you can do the redirect in PHP:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.mrquickwhip.com.au/", true, 301);
?>
```